# How to change background colour for item avatar in Ionic Framework?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to change background colour for item avatar using Ionic Framework. The problem is, it didn't change.

CSS:

```
.list.item-avatar.list-purple{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #b31f6f;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="list list-inset">
    <div class="item item-divider">
    YOUE MOVE
    </div>
    <a class="item item-avatar list-purple" href="#">
      <img src="img/venkman.jpg">
      <h2>Julia Roberts</h2>
      <p>2 days ago</p>
    </a>
    <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
      <img src="img/venkman.jpg">
      <h2>Robert De Niro</h2>
      <p>2 days ago</p>
    </a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS rule should look like this:

```
.list .item-avatar.list-purple {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #b31f6f;  
}
```

Notice that there is only one space in the CSS selector.

Comment: @Lal The html in your fiddle and the one in the question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

.item, .item-avatar, .list-purple { }

Comment: @Lal got it correct. I forgot to add . infront of other classes. Just fixed it in my solution too.